# How to pass the value from input checkbox to URL Parameters in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to update the url Parameters based on the input selected of the form.

```html
<form method="get" action="current.php" id="header-form">   
  <input type="hidden" name="location" value="location">
  <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="type" value="opt1"> option1
  <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="type" value="opt2"> option2
  <input type="checkbox" name="type2[]" class="type1" value="new1"> new1
  <input type="checkbox" name="type2[]" class="type1" value="new2"> new2
</form>
```

Jquery

By selecting the checkbox i want to append the values to the URL

My Jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".type").change(function () {
      $("#header-form").trigger("submit");
    });
    $(".type1").change(function() {
      $("#header-form").trigger("submit");
    });
  });
</script>
```

If i select option1 it works fine and if i try to select the option 2, it removes the option 1 from the URL.

If i select the option 1 & option 2

URL Should be -> http://localhost.current.php?type=option1&option2

And if i select all the values option1 & option 2 and new 1 & new 2

URL Should be -> http://localhost.current.php?type=option1&option2?type1=new1&new2

And if i select the values option1 & new 1 & new 2

URL Should be -> http://localhost.current.php?type=option1?type1=new1&new2

Comment: Do you send it as Ajax?

Comment: No, i dont know how to do it in Ajax. It will be great to send via ajax. I have php query on the page to show the results based on the url  parameters.

Comment: so why did you submit form with each checkbox change? and what is `#property`?

Comment: I want to append the values to the url.

Comment: If you use the submit button, this will happen by clicking on the submit button. Is there a reason you do not do this?

Comment: I dont want to show the submit button.

Comment: And what's your question about this? How is this even related to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep the previous submit data.
do this with PHP:

```
<form method="get" action="current.php" id="header-form">

    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="location">
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && in_array('opt1', $_GET['type'])): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> class="type" value="opt1"> option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && in_array('opt2', $_GET['type'])): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> class="type" value="opt2"> option2

    <input type="checkbox" name="type2[]" <?php if(isset($_GET['type2']) && in_array('new1', $_GET['type2'])): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> class="type1" value="new1"> new1
    <input type="checkbox" name="type2[]" <?php if(isset($_GET['type2']) && in_array('new2', $_GET['type2'])): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> class="type1" value="new2"> new2

</form>
```

Comment: Now it keeps the value selected from the URL. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, there is a issue, the url works as expected, but the check box selected value is incorrect, if i select only opt2, after the page load, the selected option is [op1] instead of opt2.

Comment: @user2468312 sorry, you're right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2468312 you're welcome.